# Couldn't understand why the Regexp option i got disabled in my code

Tags: ruby, regex

I have just started playing with Ruby and I'm stuck on something. Is
there some trick to modify the `casefold attribute` of a Regexp object after
it's been instantiated?

*The best idea what I tried is the following:*

```
irb(main):001:0> a = Regexp.new('a')
=> /a/
irb(main):002:0> aA = Regexp.new(a.to_s, Regexp::IGNORECASE)
=> /(?-mix:a)/i
```

*But none of the below seems to work:*

```
irb(main):003:0> a =~ 'a'
=> 0
irb(main):004:0> a =~ 'A'
=> nil
irb(main):005:0> aA =~ 'a'
=> 0
irb(main):006:0> aA =~ 'A'
=> nil
```

Something I don't understand is happening here. Where did the 'i' go on line
8?

```
irb(main):07:0> aA = Regexp.new(a.to_s, Regexp::IGNORECASE)
=> /(?-mix:a)/i
irb(main):08:0> aA.to_s
=> "(?-mix:a)"
irb(main):09:0>
```

I am using Ruby 1.9.3.

I am also unable understand the below code: why returning `false`:

```
/(?i:a)/.casefold?      #=> false
```

Comment: be careful using the phrase 'seems to work' -  a reader cannot always guess what you expected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Frederick already explains, calling `to_s` on a regex will add modifiers around it that ensure that its properties like case-sensitiveness are preserved. So if you insert a case-sensitive regex into a case-insensitive regex, the inserted part will still be case-sensitive. Likewise the modifiers given to Regexp.new will have no effect if the first argument is a regex or the result of calling to_s on one.

To solve this issue, call `source` on the regex instead of `to_s`. Unlike `to_s`, `source` simply returns the source of regex without adding anything:

```
aA = Regexp.new(a.source, Regexp::IGNORECASE)
```

> I am also unable understand the below code: why returning false:
>
> ```
> /(?i:a)/.casefold?
> ```

Because `(?i:...)` sets the `i` flag locally, not globally. It only applies to the part of the regex within the parentheses, not the whole regex. Of course in this case the whole regex is within the parentheses, but that doesn't matter as far as methods like `casefold?` are concerned.

Comment: I think second part is not been answered. Could you tell me the reason of getting `false` value?

Comment: @RubyTheBang Because `(?i)` sets the i flag locally, not globally. It only applies to the part of the regex within the parentheses, not the whole regex. Of course in this case the whole regex is within the parentheses, but that doesn't matter as far as methods like `casefold?` are concerned.

Comment: @perfect! `+1` to you.You guys are awesome :)

Comment: in the line's `aA = Regexp.new(a.to_s, Regexp::IGNORECASE)` output :- `=> /(?-mix:a)/i` --- why or how `-m,x` options came,whereas i only enable `i` option durin `regex` object creation?

Comment: @RubyTheBang The regex `/a/` doesn't have the flags m, i or x. So when you call `to_s` on it, you get a string representation that explicitly disables all those flags, so that, as I said, if you insert the regex into another regex, those properties will remain unchanged for the inserted part, even if the other regex has different properties globally.

Comment: just one information i need from you(not related to the post),if you have no problem- is how to clear the `IRB` screen if needed?

Comment: I want to cealr the screen data in IRB. that asking me such `irb(main):015:0>
Display all 160 possibilities? (y or n).' I pressed on `y` gave huge list. I want to clear the content of `IRB`, the way I did `cls` in `microsoft command prompt`.

Comment: @RubyTheBang And Ctrl-l doesn't work for that? It works for me.

Answer (score 2):

Since the result of `to_s` is just the regular expression string itself - no delimiters or external flags - the flags are translated into the `(?i:...)` syntax that sets or clears them temporarily inside the expression itself.  This lets you get a `Regexp` object back out via a simple `Regexp.new(s)` call that will match the same strings.

The wrapping, unfortunately, includes explicitly clearing the flags that are *not* set on the object.  So your first regex gets stringified into something between `(?:-i...)` - that is, the `casefold` option is explicitly turned *off* between the parentheses.  Turning it back on for the object doesn't have any effect.

You can use `a.source` instead of `a.to_s` to get just the original expression, without the flag settings:

```
irb(main):001:0> a=/a/
=> /a/
irb(main):002:0> aA = Regexp.new(a.source, Regexp::IGNORECASE)
=> /a/i
irb(main):003:0> a =~ 'a'
=> 0
irb(main):004:0> a =~ 'A'
=> nil
irb(main):005:0> aA =~ 'a'
=> 0
irb(main):006:0> aA =~ 'A'
=> 0
```

Comment: The OP's question was why `aA` doesn't match `'A'` (which it doesn't - the OP seems to be perfectly aware that `ß` means there was a match, but `aA =~ 'A'` returns `nil`).

Comment: `+1` to you also for explaining the reason!

Answer (score 2):

As your console output shows, `a.to_s` includes the case sensitiveness as an option for your subexpression, so `aA` is being defined as

```
/(?-mix:a)/i
```

so you're asking ruby for a regular expression that is case insensitive, but the only thing in that case insensitive regexp is a group for when case sensitivity has be turned on, so the net effect is that 'a' is matched case sensitively